# Why does 'focus-within' not work in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, css, safari

i have a site i developing for my friend for fun and I'm having trouble with CSS. I followed a tutorial from https://www.fireship.io about theme changing. My problem is that when I click theme on safari my dropdown won't well... dropdown. (ps. it works fine on any other browser)

```js
// DOM Elements

const darkButton = document.getElementById("dark");
const lightButton = document.getElementById("light");
const solarButton = document.getElementById("solar");
const body = document.body;

// Apply the cached theme on reload

const theme = localStorage.getItem("theme");
const isSolar = localStorage.getItem("isSolar");

if (theme) {
    body.classList.add(theme);
    isSolar && body.classList.add("solar");
}

// Button Event Handlers

darkButton.onclick = () => {
    body.classList.replace("light", "dark");
    localStorage.setItem("theme", "dark");
};

lightButton.onclick = () => {
    body.classList.replace("dark", "light");

    localStorage.setItem("theme", "light");
};

solarButton.onclick = () => {
    if (body.classList.contains("solar")) {
        body.classList.remove("solar");
        localStorage.removeItem("isSolar");
    } else {
        body.classList.add("solar");
        localStorage.setItem("isSolar", true);
    }
};
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@200;300;400;500&display=swap");

* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 10vh;
    background: var(--bg-nav);
    font-family: "Poppins", sans-serif;
}

.logo {
    color: var(--text);
    text-transform: capitalize;
    letter-spacing: 5px;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 20;
}

.nav-links {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    width: 50%;
}

.nav-links a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: var(--text);
    font-weight: 300;
    letter-spacing: 3px;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.nav-links li {
    list-style: none;
}

.burger {
    display: none;
}

.burger div {
    width: 25px;
    height: 2px;
    background-color: var(--burger-color);
    margin: 6px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.contact {
    background-color: rgb(37, 192, 192);
    padding: 8px 30px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    color: var(--text);
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 14px;
}

.contact:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
}

.dropdown {
    position: absolute;
    width: 500px;
    opacity: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    background: var(--bg-dropdown);
    border-top: 2px solid var(--border-color);

    border-bottom-right-radius: 8px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 8px;

    display: flex;
    display: none;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 3rem;
    margin-top: 1.22rem;
    padding: 0.5rem;

    box-shadow: rgba(2, 8, 20, 0.1) 0px 0.175em 0.5em;
    transform: translateX(-40%);

    transition: opacity 0.15s ease-out;
}

.hasDropdown:hover .dropdown {
    display: flex;
    opacity: 1;
    pointer-events: auto;
}

.dropdown-item a {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    size: 0.7rem;
    padding-left: 10px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.dropdown-item a::before {
    content: " ";
    border: 2px solid var(--border-color);
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 2rem;
    height: 2rem;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1024px) {
    .nav-links {
        width: 60%;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 90vh;
        top: 10vh;
        background-color: rgb(87, 87, 87);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 50%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.4s ease-in;
        z-index: 1;
    }

    .nav-links li {
        opacity: 0;
        background-color: gray;
        padding: 5px 35px;
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    .burger {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
    body {
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }

    .nav-links {
        position: absolute;
        right: 0px;
        height: 90vh;
        top: 10vh;
        background-color: rgb(87, 87, 87);
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
        width: 100%;
        transform: translateX(100%);
        transition: transform 0.4s ease-in;
    }

    .nav-links li,
    button {
        opacity: 0;
    }

    .burger {
        display: block;
        cursor: pointer;
    }
}

.nav-active {
    transform: translateX(0%);
}

@keyframes navLinkFade {
    from {
        opacity: 0;
        transform: translateX(50px);
    }
    to {
        opacity: 1;
        transform: translateX(0px);
    }
}

.toggle .line1 {
    transform: rotate(-45deg) translate(-5px, 6px);
}

.toggle .line2 {
    opacity: 0;
}

.toggle .line3 {
    transform: rotate(45deg) translate(-5px, -6px);
}

:root {
    --white: #ffffff;
    --gray0: #f8f8f8;
    --gray1: #dbe1e8;
    --gray2: #b2becd;
    --gray3: #6c7983;
    --gray4: #454e56;
    --gray5: #2a2e35;
    --gray6: #12181b;
    --black: #000000;
    --blue: #0084a5;
    --purple: #a82dd1;
    --yellow: #fff565;
}

.light {
    --bg: var(--gray3);
    --bg-nav: linear-gradient(to right, var(--gray1), var(--gray3));
    --bg-dropdown: var(--gray0);
    --text: var(--gray6);
    --border-color: var(--blue);
    --bg-solar: var(--yellow);
    --burger-color: var(--black);
}

.dark {
    --bg: var(--gray5);
    --bg-nav: linear-gradient(to right, var(--gray5), var(--gray6));
    --bg-dropdown: var(--gray6);
    --text: var(--gray0);
    --border-color: var(--purple);
    --bg-solar: var(--blue);
    --burger-color: var(--white);
}

.solar {
    --gray0: #fbffd4;
    --gray1: #f7f8d0;
    --gray2: #b6f880;
    --gray3: #5ec72d;
    --gray4: #3ea565;
    --gray5: #005368;
    --gray6: #003d4c;
}

#dark::before {
    background: #2a2e35;
}

#light::before {
    background: #ffffff;
}

#solar::before {
    background: var(--bg-solar);
}
```

```html
<nav>
    <div class="logo">
        Jeno
    </div>
    <ul class="nav-links">
        <li><a href="pages/projects.html">Projects</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li class="hasDropdown">
            <a href="#">Theme</a>
            <ul class="dropdown">
                <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <a id="light" href="#">light</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <a id="dark" href="#">dark</a>
                </li>
                <li class="dropdown-item">
                    <a id="solar" href="#">solarize</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <button class="contact">Contact</button>
    </ul>
    <div class="burger">
        <div class="line1"></div>
        <div class="line2"></div>
        <div class="line3"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

(this snippet won't work so here is the codepen: https://codepen.io/ksaeidnia0/pen/VwvrEBr)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Safari needs a tabindex. Add it like this:

```
<li class="nav-item has-dropdown" tabindex="0" >
```

You'll also get an ugly focus indicator ring which you can remove:

```
.has-dropdown:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Why does Safari need the tabIndex when there is an anchor tag within the li?

Comment: This only fixes :hover for me, but not the focus